# CartoDB - "sql applied has errors" message - where can I see the error text?

Tags: sql, carto

I'm still getting my bearings with the interface it seems...

When running a SQL query in CartoDB against a table... it seems like a get the correct result, but I also get a see a "sql applied has errors" message when I hover over the SQL icon which has both a red and a green dot displayed on it.  Is there any way to see the particular error message?  I don't see a place to get that info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean errors using the **Editor**??

Otherwise, if you are using for example CartoDB.js, you could check and debug the requests made by browser. For example, with Google Chrome, you could open [Google Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and look at Network tab. There, you could check the errors request (red). And there, you can find the error returned by the database.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific. I'm logged into cartodb.com and using the Editor.  If I have Firefox Firebug open when I click the "Apply Query" button, I see some GET and PUT requests showing up in Firebug.  I think... at this point maybe it was a lingering error.  Because if I break it by using an incorrect column name, I get the message, then if I fix it I still see the message until I apply query a second time.  Anyway, I'm going to put this aside, I think I just need to refresh the query...

Comment: Yes, I think so too. You need to refresh the query. :)